# How to have the values merged into a single array when using $addFields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm a newbie to MongoDB and basically from RDBMS. I'm using $addFields to retrieve a single column from a join table as follows,

`Movies` collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd30088ccbfc800173dcd42"),
    "name" : "NGK",
    "sourceId" : "5cd3007cccbfc800173dcd41"
}
```

`Events` collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa8b20ee38ea10717b3e72"),
    "movieId" : ObjectId("5cd720dda185d600170278fd"),
    "type" : "news",
    "description" : "Kathua rape, murder case verdict LIVE updates: Victim's family likely to challenge verdict giving life term to three main accused",
    "resources" :{
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            {
                "_v" : 1560167750,
                "image" : "xxxx/posters/orgomohvopr0ykxgmq2g"
            }, 
            {
                "_v" : 1560167752,
                "image" : "xxxx/posters/bnskv36qbdj9wnaomvre"
            }
        ],
        "youtubeLinks" : [ 
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocnzgwjXdLw", 
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLRHNYQ-Dno"
        ]
    },
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-06-07T16:04:48.980Z")
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa8d03e8604410c74a65ab"),
    "movieId" : ObjectId("5cd720dda185d600170278fd"),
    "sourceId" : ObjectId("5cfa0bb8f5b21607b245eff3"),
    "type" : "news",
    "description" : "Former Pakistani president Asif Ali Zardari arrested on corruption charges",
    "resources" : {
        "posterLinks" : [ 
            {
                "_v" : 1560167915,
                "image" : "xxxx/posters/ldu3iceqarnaaw1qeyhk"
            }, 
            {
                "_v" : 1560167917,
                "image" : "xxxx/posters/r1oi172lpxdylnqaify5"
            }
        ]
    },
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-06-07T16:12:51.927Z")
}
```

My Query:

```
db.getCollection('movies').aggregate([
   {
        $lookup: {
            from: "events",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "movieId",
            as: "events"
        }
   },
   { 
       $addFields: { 
           "resources": "$events.resources"
        }
   }
]);
```

The result is as follows,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd720dda185d600170278fd"),
    "action" : [ 
        "5cf35c027807f0f65b5e9627"
    ],
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa8b20ee38ea10717b3e72"),
            "movieId" : ObjectId("5cd720dda185d600170278fd"),
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("5cfa0bb8f5b21607b245eff3"),
            "type" : "news",
            "description" : "Kathua rape, murder case verdict LIVE updates: Victim's family likely to challenge verdict giving life term to three main accused",
            "resources" :{
                "posterLinks" : [ 
                    {
                        "_v" : 1560167750,
                        "image" : "xxxx/posters/orgomohvopr0ykxgmq2g"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_v" : 1560167752,
                        "image" : "xxxx/posters/bnskv36qbdj9wnaomvre"
                    }
                ],
                "youtubeLinks" : [ 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocnzgwjXdLw", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLRHNYQ-Dno"
                ]
            },
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-06-07T16:04:48.980Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa8d03e8604410c74a65ab"),
            "movieId" : ObjectId("5cd720dda185d600170278fd"),
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("5cfa0bb8f5b21607b245eff3"),
            "type" : "news",
            "description" : "Former Pakistani president Asif Ali Zardari arrested on corruption charges",
            "resources" : {
                "posterLinks" : [ 
                    {
                        "_v" : 1560167915,
                        "image" : "xxxx/posters/ldu3iceqarnaaw1qeyhk"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "_v" : 1560167917,
                        "image" : "xxxx/posters/r1oi172lpxdylnqaify5"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-06-07T16:12:51.927Z")
        }, 
    "resources" : [ 
        {
            "posterLinks" : [ 
                {
                    "_v" : 1560167750,
                    "image" : "xxxx/posters/orgomohvopr0ykxgmq2g"
                }, 
                {
                    "_v" : 1560167752,
                    "image" : "xxxx/posters/bnskv36qbdj9wnaomvre"
                }
            ],
            "youtubeLinks" : [ 
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocnzgwjXdLw", 
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLRHNYQ-Dno"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "posterLinks" : [ 
                {
                    "_v" : 1560167915,
                    "image" : "xxxx/posters/ldu3iceqarnaaw1qeyhk"
                }, 
                {
                    "_v" : 1560167917,
                    "image" : "xxxx/posters/r1oi172lpxdylnqaify5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the expected result, but as you can see when there's more than events for a movie, there are multiple arrays in resources when a movie has more than one event.

I'm looking for a way to get single resources array for each movie with single `posterLinks` and `youtubeLinks` object, I'm aware that this can be achieved by using a loop after the values are retrieved. But is there a way to do this in the query itself?

Also I don't need the events array again in the result as the required resources are already available in the result. Any suggestions on this would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the expected output.

Comment: Are resources always only posterLinks and youtubeLinks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary resources you can use [sub-query syntax of lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

Something like this:

```
db.getCollection('movies').aggregate([
    {
       $lookup:
         {
            from: "events",
            let: { movieId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [ 
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$movieId", "$$movieId"] } } },
                { $project: { resources: { $objectToArray: "$resources" } } },
                { $unwind: "$resources" },
                { $unwind: "$resources.v" },
                { $group: { _id:"$resources.k", "v": { $addToSet:"$resources.v" } } },
                { $group: { _id:null, resources: { $push: { k:"$_id", v:"$v" } } } },
                { $project: { resources: { $arrayToObject: "$resources" } } },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot:"$resources" } }
            ],
            as: "events"
         }
    },
    { $project: { resources:0 } },
    { $unwind: "$events" }
]);
```

The pipeline within lookup groups resources by keys.
It allows duplicate resources in the resulting array. If it is not intended the sub-query pipeline should be amended accordingly.

Bear in mind it's quite expensive query. If structure of resources is predefined and stable you can make the query more efficient by using array functions with hardcoded keys in the main pipeline instead.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you very much for your response. It's working for most of the cases except when there's no reference like no when there is no `references` array in the document, it's not including it in the result.

Comment: @Stranger Sorry I don't follow, what is the `references` array? Are you sure you commented to the right question?

Comment: Sorry, it's not references, it's resources

Comment: I mean to say when there's a document with the key references, it's not being fetched and only fetching the document where the "resources" is present.

Comment: Dear Stranger, you never mentioned documents may have "references" field nor what you expect in the result in such cases. You are not new to SO and know how it works. The only information we have is what you posted in the question. Besides the answer illustrates the approach - adjust the pipeline to meet your particular needs.